# What is the exact meaning of "depth_registration" in openni.launch?

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the exact meaning of "depth_registration" in openni.launch?

I use Asus Xtion. If I set it to "true", does it produce point clouds using camera hardware?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198320/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-%22depth_registration%22-in-openni.launch?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

depth_registration as a parameter really means "hardware depth_registration". When it is enabled, the camera itself rectifies and aligns the depth and color images as best it can to produce images that are registered to one another using the factory calibration. If disabled, registration will need to be done using the components of image_pipeline (meaning it happens on  your cpu)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1